# Search textfield Results not selectable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, textfield

I'm using UITextFields as my search bars. I had to do this because I have multiple inputs for people to search for. The search is working perfectly. In fact the text field is working better than a normal search bar memory wise. The only problem is that I cannot select the resulting cell. When I press the cell nothing at all happens. I even put a log statement in didselect and the cell is not even getting the action. Help please.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.ASearch.delegate = self;
    self.BSearch.delegate = self;

    NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Location" attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor] }];

    self.ASearch.attributedPlaceholder = str;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self dismissKeyboard];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [ASearch resignFirstResponder];
    [BSearch resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    [Asearch becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 75;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (searchArray.count == 0) {

        UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

        messageLabel.text = @"Search!";
        messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        messageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT" size:20];
        [messageLabel sizeToFit];

        self.tableView.backgroundView = messageLabel;

        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

        return 0;
    } else {

        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

    return searchArray.count;
    }
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    headerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 90.0, 320.0, 90.0)];
    return headerView;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"searchCell";

   TopCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject *searchObject = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.AImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultThumbnail"];
    cell.AImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    cell.AImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.AName.text = [searchObject objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.addressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@",[searchObject objectForKey:@"address"],[searchObject objectForKey:@"city"], [searchObject objectForKey:@"state"]];
    cell.placeType.text = [searchObject objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if (textField == ASearch) {

    NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithString:placeSearch.text];

    searchString = [searchString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    [self searchDataBase:searchString];

    return YES;

    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

-(void)searchDataBase: (NSString *)subString {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"HotSpots"];
    [query whereKey:@"name" matchesRegex:subString modifiers:@"i"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        searchArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:objects];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"%lu", objects.count);
    }];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [self dismissKeyboard];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [self searchDataBase:textField.text];
    [ASearch resignFirstResponder];
    [BSearch resignFirstResponder];
    [self dismissKeyboard];
    return YES;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"Segue"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexpath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        HSBarTableViewController *Controller = (HSBarTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        PFObject *pObject = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

        Controller.arObject = pObject;
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender:self];
    NSLog(@"Pressed");
}
```

Comment: Is this code in a UIViewController or a UITableViewController? It could be that your tap gesture recognizer is interfering with the table view's recognizers. Put a log in the dismissKeyboard method and see if that's called when you try to select a cell.

Comment: Yes dismiss keyboard is being called everytime i press a cell. How can I avoid this?

Comment: If I comment out the tap recognizer it works...Is there a way to implement to tap too?

Comment: I got it..I just commented out my dismiss keyboard method and let the return key handle it...Thanks again rdelmar!